# TypeScript: What does {[key: string]: any} means as return type of a function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently learning TypeScript and Angular. While reading about Custom validators I came across the following piece of code from https://angular.io/guide/form-validation.

```
export function forbiddenNameValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenName': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

I don't really understand what return type of the inner function ie `{[key: string]: any}` means? I understand `key:string` part, ie Object's key is of type string but what exactly `{[key: string]: any}`  means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the function returns an object that you can index into with any string value; the property's result value type is `any` meaning it can be, well, anything. (The `| null` means it can also return `null` instead of returning an actual object.)

```
Object −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−v
                                        {[key: string]: any}
Key of all properties is any string −−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^−−−−− type of all
                                                                 properties is `any`
```

It's a **very** broad type.

More in [the documentation of index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures).

Comment: From the documentation that you've linked, I think the correct terminology is "index signatures", not "index types". See this section for more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures

Answer (score -1):

It returns an object, like

```
{
   "name": "John"
}
```

or

```
{
   "length": 5
}
```